# Problem installing ADT in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I've already installed the SDK and now I need the Eclipse plugin. However, it won't work. It gets to about 25-29% and hangs for a few minutes, then fails and I get this error message:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=SDKProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unable to read repository at
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_12.0.0.v201106281929-138431.jar.
>   Read timed out

I'm using Windows Vista and running Eclipse under administrative privileges.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I meet this problem too. What I have done was downloaded the offline package, here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#troubleshooting . Hope I helped :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked properly! I'll choose your answer as the answer once it allows me!

Answer (score 16):

I've solved this applying the fix that [frogman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326193/frogman) suggests here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10103295/106342

I reproduce it here:

> Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”

The checkbox mentioned there is in the dialog that shows up when you hit "Install new software".

Answer (score 0):

Download the ADT Plugin zip file

[ADT Plugin Zip File](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.3.zip)

- Start Eclipse, then select *Help* > *Install New Software*.
- Click *Add*, in the top-right corner.
- In the *Add Repository* dialog, click *Archive*.
- Select the downloaded ADT-20.0.3.zip file and click OK.
- Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
- In the *Available Software* dialog, select the checkbox next to *Developer Tools* and click *Next*.
- In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click *Next*.
- Read and accept the license agreements, then click *Finish*.

If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

[Page link fore study](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. Tried the answer above, and still getting this:

An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.

I'm running Win 7 Premium on a Dell Laptop 64bit