# No repository found error in Installing ADT in eclipse Indigo

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

This error comes when I try to install ADT:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
```

An eclipse Java EE version and I'm following [This](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing). Platform is Windows.

Comment: In case you don't mind adding a second, fresh Eclipse install: Get *eclipse classic* or *Eclipse IDE for Java developers* instead. These work with the ADT plugin out of the box. *(thats what I do usually when I get such an error, saves a lot of time. Eclipse depencies can be very anoying at times)*

Answer (score 344):

Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software” (this is causing the error message above).

Comment: this worked! Thank you :) I downloaded the plugin manually but even then it gave me the same error until I checked the option.

Comment: Makes me wonder why "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" is checked by default.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This option was checked by default and updates failed everytime and after I unchecked it the  eclipse updates worked on the first go. This has been a problem that continually frustrated me to no end and has at long last been solved. If I could upvote this answer a thousand times I would do it. Alas I can not do that so I give you one thousand thank yous, instead. Thank You very much. One thousand thank yous my good sir.

Answer (score 46):

Just had the same issue.

I removed the **http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/**
site and then re-added it, then everything downloaded fine.

Comment: I had trouble with the ADT and other updates, and this solved it all. Thanks!

Comment: Similar for me, except that I removed and re-added the https version of the mentioned url.

Answer (score 23):

for the latest update, I had to use the url

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Please note the "https" as well as the "/" at the end of the url.

Comment: This worked for me- but I had to remove the previous android file location under  install new software - availabl software and replacing it with this: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: This also worked for me - while the above answers didn't. For the record I didn't have to remove any previous packages, just had to add this one.

Answer (score 7):

My initial ADT URL was `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` and that was giving me this error.

I solved it by replacing `https` with `http` and running the update again.

Answer (score 5):

As @ZainAli suggested I also solved this for the 21.1 Android SDK Tools update by removing the `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` site and re-added it. To do that click on the "Available Software Sites" link in the Available Software dialog and remove appropriately. Then come back to the Help / Install New Software and re-add it. I would post a picture if I had the rep.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the site http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse from the list of sites, restarted eclipse, invoked Help/Update, re-added the site http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/, invoked Help/Update again, which now runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Updating from Kepler SR1 to Kepler SR2 solved this for me. 
I've just installed over the existing installation, so none of my settings were harmed.

Win8.1, 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem very easily in windows.

**Go to** Control Panel **->** Network and Sharing Center **->** Windows Firewall **->** Turn off Windows Firewall

And try to install again and see the magic :)

Answer (score -1):

Please, 
check link
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

configration your eclips.

Install New Software in your eclips,
put this link
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

and install edit