# ADT needs to update but find no update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, update-site

Today I installed API8 from the SDK manager, previously I only had been working with API14. After the SDK manager was done, and upon restarting ADT I got this error:

> This android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.1.0
>   and above. Current version is 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58.

So I click to find updates but I get "no updates found".

**I did the following:**

- Used the SDK manager to re-install android SDK tools (rev 21.1).
- Used the SDK manager to re-install API8 and API14.

Still no go :(

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had the same issue. Please try the following in eclipse

Help --> Install new software

Then choose "Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" from the drop down list and update the ADT

IF THIS THROWS ERROR Like this

No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685

***Modify http: to https:***

Sample : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

And then update ADT. This method worked for me.

Comment: This was exactly the problem with an ADT Bundle installation on one of my machines. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks, it worked for me too (ADT bundle on Mac)

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, only I had to replace https with http.

Answer (score 44):

You get that issue when your eclipse ADT plugin version doesn't match your SDK tools version.

Have you tried updating the ADT plugin in eclipse?

Help -> Install New Software and then using the [ADT update site](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) should work.

If you get a `No Respository Found` error using this site, you should use the [HTTPS version](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) instead.

If you're still having trouble getting it to install, you can download the zip standalone and manually install it. You can find the latest zip and installation instructions at the [ADT troubleshooting page.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting)

Comment: I did find Android Development Tools using you method, but after excepting the terms i got an error "Installing Software has encounterd a problem. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed". Details shows alot of errors like this "No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685"

Comment: Huh, you might need to download the zip file and do it locally instead. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting for further details

Comment: haha I still get the same error... I'm going to re download and install the ADT bundle

Comment: Ah, that's a shame :/ Well good luck with the ADT bundle anyway and hopefully you don't come across this error again next time ADT updates.

Comment: This also happens with ADT bundle, enabling ADT HTTPS update site sometimes helps

Answer (score 12):

If problem in "http".

- 1) Help --> "Install new software" --> "Available Software Sites"
- 2) Click on "Android Developer Tools Update Site"
- 3) Click "Edit"
- **4) Mofify "http" to "https"**
- 5) Click "Ok" --> "Ok"
- 6) Try update again.

Comment: I'm using ADT bundle and having problem with the latest update. This helped.

Comment: This answer helped me to update ADT plugin in latest ADT bundle.

Answer (score 8):

I tried all methods mentioned here, but still without success.
What finally helped was the tip from [No repository found error in Installing ADT in eclipse Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499563/no-repository-found-error-in-installing-adt-in-eclipse-indigo):

> Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”

Answer (score 7):

you Should Update your ADT to Latest Version by below way.

> Eclipse--> Go to Help--> Install New Software --> Add--> Inside Add Repository
>   Write Name="ADT"(as you want) and
>   Location="https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" --> after
>   loading some times you will get Developer Tools & NDK Plugins-->
>   checked both if you want to install Use NDK as future Use or checked
>   only developer Tool--> click Next--> Finish.

After this you can Update your SDK to latest Version.

Hope it will Help.

Comment: I checked both, but i get an error saying "Installing Software has encounterd a problem. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed". In the details it displays alot of lines like this "No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685".

Answer (score 4):

Got this one too, going from ADT 22.3 to 23.

Not sure what's keeping Eclipse from finding the updates (maybe some IDs changed or something), but **the solution is to install the ADT plugins over the existing ones using Help -> Install New Software**, just select the same site, no need to correct the URL from *https* to *http* or vice versa. The wizard will tell you there are a bunch of conflicts that'll result in removing the old versions of the plugins -- that's ok, go for it.

**UPD** Seemingly, (as at least one person downvoted the answer), installing new version over old one forcefully doesn't work for everyone. Here's [the related bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72584) where it's said that the old installation of Exclipse/ADT is hopelessly unupdatable and one should just download the new bundle to resolve this.

**PS** Anyway, you should be using Android Studio by now. Compared to Eclipse, it's a memory hog and has a very different feel to it and different hotkeys, but *(as much as I hate to say it having been a snuggled up Eclipse user for a long time)* it's way better, at least for Android development.

Comment: "Next" button is disabled. I can't do that.

Comment: @daVe Can you get a screenshot of that?

Comment: I've already re-installed Eclipse. It was the fast way to solve to problem. But check it out yourself: try to install the same ADT version you already have (don't "Hide items that are already installed") and you will get the same window as I got with **Next** and **Finish** buttons disabled, but with a different error detail.

Comment: Hm, than your case must have been different from mine. For me, the wizard just complained about conflicting plugins but it was just a warning that old ones were going to be removed, and _Next_ was enabled.

Comment: Your wizard was clever than mine. I was using the Eclipse ADT Bundle from Google by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here, but luckily it is resolved now. The help->install new software and the android tool manager didn't help.

I re-downloaded the ADT bundle and simply copied over the failing installation, it works now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem last weekend. Go to Help->Install new Software. Here use Android Developer Tools Update Site url - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/, two options should appear and I can't remember which one to choose ;) (It should be the one with DEV)

I don't think it is necessary but before I removed and downloaded the whole Eclipse with ADT. But it should not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks! just like Seans answer :) But It doesnt work as you can read in my comment