# Updating Eclipse SDK Error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, updates

I updated my SDK, and now it says I need to have the SDK which I already have.  When I check for updates and try to update the options, I get this:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
```

Any ideas for a fix??  I have tried everything!

Comment: Have you updated ADT plugin as well?

Comment: Um I am not sure.  I thought I updated everything.  How do I update that?

Comment: Help --> Check for Updates      is where I am getting these repository errors from.

Comment: I faced the same issue. ended up using a fresh ADT bundle.

Comment: How do I get a fresh ADT bundle?

Comment: @SamuelKnox get the ADT bundle [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: so redownload the entire program?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15266892/2024272
It worked for me.
Hope it helps. You can also checkout this: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*uncheck* "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"

see [Can not install Android ADT 21.1 on eclipse Juno (Windows 7) after upadate to SDK 21.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866656/can-not-install-android-adt-21-1-on-eclipse-juno-windows-7-after-upadate-to-sd)