# This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or above. Current version is 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3, eclipse-adt

I updated the SDK to the latest version i.e 22.0.0 from help>>install new software and then I put the url " http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ " there then I ticked "Developer Tools" and "NDK Plugin" then it says 
 Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Tracer for OpenGL ES" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Native Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.

Please help! Anyone

Answer (score 15):

What worked for me was the following following :

1- Go to Help->Install New software

2- Where it says "Work with" select "Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"

3-After the refresh select "Developer Tools" and "NDK Plugins" , Make sure you select the main Branch

4-Click next

5-The following message should be under details "your Original request has been modified" "Android DDMS is already installed, so an update will be preformed instead"

6- Click Next and Accept the terms, and you are done.

Comment: That worked for me too.
This guy says the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-4latest-version-from-22-0-1

Comment: I just did this and then received another error - No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse - I found the cure in this post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499563/no-repository-found-error-in-installing-adt-in-eclipse-indigo - to fix this next error copy the url and add it as a new link. Then download   this appears to have fixed my issue. I've been round the houses with this - I have ticked 4 separate answers that have got me a step closer

Comment: Glad the other post helped, you found the other link, it worked for the newer version as well

Comment: +1 Thanks. This worked around an issue in Luna for me where ADT couldn't be installed at all through the marketplace.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem last week, I tried everything, but nothing helped me.

Finally fixed it only by re-downloading ADT bundle whole again.

Give a try before everything through [**https**://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) not http

Comment: It says the same thing

Comment: I knew that because I tried them all, you have 64 or 32 bit edition (I'm having 64 bit one)

Comment: Some had luck by adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to end eclipse.ini file which enables IpV4 download for Help->Update. or it will seek only IpV6.

Comment: I've a worst case solution, however before that I want to know whether you updated adt to 22 through sdk manager ?

Comment: yes, I updated to Android API 18 through SDK manager and updated to 22 thorugh the install new software and all

Comment: Is there any platforms showing inside Window-> Preference/Android ? If none, try to set the sdk location

Comment: from all option the one that worked for me was going to eclipse , and add new plugin "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" and install all the items.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-4latest-version-from-22-0-1

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by doing this:

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Click Popular Tab (or in Installed tab) -> Search for "Android Development Tools for Eclipse" -> click Update button.

Comment: I don't see Eclipse Marketplace under help.

Answer (score 1):

if you update sdk and then you get that error "This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or above.  Current version is 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.  Please update ADT to the latest version."

then you can u do that steps which JFDionne   tell ....

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Click Popular Tab (or in Installed tab) -> Search for "Android Development Tools for Eclipse" -> click Update button.

my problem is also fixed by doing above steps .....

Answer (score 0):

For me, the auto-update feature from eclipse wasn't working. 
So I manually downloaded the eclipse adt from the [Android site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting). 
Extracted the zip and used it as a new local site for plugins. 
It installs and restarts the eclipse and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

***Solved this problem in Ubuntu 12:04 LTS running Eclipse as root.***

> sudo eclipse