# No repository found error while downloading Eclipse plugin for BB10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am using this site to download eclipse plugin to develop Blackberry 10 application. "http://developer.blackberry.com/android/downloads/eclipseplugin"...

But I get this error when I try to download

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.2.1.v201309180102-833290
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.2.1.v201309180102-833290
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.2.1.v201309180102-833290
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.2.1.v201309180102-833290
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.2.1.v201309180102-833290
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.2.1.v201309180102-833290
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.2.1.v201309180102-833290

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answered by frogman [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499563/no-repository-found-error-in-installing-adt-in-eclipse-indigo)

> Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software” (this is causing the error message above).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Windows / Preferences
Then.. Install / Update 
Then..Available Update Sites
And last...
Check All Sites!!
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
AND
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/  (sometimes are unchecked and fails)

Answer (score 0):

## Trailing / in *Available Software Sites*

The `No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,...` problem seem to be related to many things or be the symptom to different problems.

Adding to [the answer from @miguel-a-cardenete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19455608/5108777), make sure all URLs there have a '/' at the end. It worked for me in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2.

Comes from #2 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897080/5108777).