# updating my ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse

Sir, my ADT version is 22.0.5 and i want to update it. But when i click on "Check for updates" i get the Dialog that "No updates available" .Then i tried to install it by putting the url "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" then ticking on developer toole>Android Developer Tools and then by hitting next and then finish......then i get the error that "'Installing' Software has encountered a problem
An error occured while collecting items to be installed"

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826

Answer (score 5):

The solution is here:

[No repository found error in Installing ADT in eclipse Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499563/no-repository-found-error-in-installing-adt-in-eclipse-indigo?rq=1)

Simply, uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”

Answer (score 0):

Goto help -> install new software . place the below link .

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/

then it gave options
cive wat ever you want
give
and install. Happy installing :)

update me thats wat you need or something .

Comment: Thanks Sir ....but Sir in this link there is no option for ADT update........all i want is to update my ADT version to 22.3.0....which will support my SDK version of API 19

Comment: If you do this , it let you to eclipse juno. And after that you can update through SDK manager. Thats wat you want i think.

Answer (score 0):

ADT 22.3 requires Eclipse Helios or higher so if you do not have that you will have to update Eclipse. See [ADT Plugin](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) for details.