# ADT plugin Error in Windows Vista? Read timed out

Tags: android

I installed Eclipse INDIGO and JDK 1.6 in Vista. I follow the steps

Help -> Install new software -> Followed the **Downloading the ADT Plugin**. After accept the licence agreement it started installing on Background at that time it shows an error like

**Installing software has encountered a problem**

On **Details** Button it shows the complete Error like,

> **An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Unable to read repository at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar.
>   Read timed out**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, I would say try again. The file stated in the error message is available for me, while it says "Read timed out" in your message.

For an alternative, look here: [Problem installing ADT in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129246/problem-installing-adt-in-eclipse)

Comment: I have one doubt on the proxy settings in eclipse, Will I check the HTTP option ?