# An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

When I tried to update my Android SDK, I got the following errors. What should I do?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.0.5.v201307292155--757759
```

Comment: restart eclipse and try one more time

Comment: Just Do one thing... Restart Eclipse.........

Comment: for a generic solution to `No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,...` check this particular answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15897080/5108777

Answer (score 27):

I just had this issue... and I went back into Window->Preferences->Install/Update and for the setting of the update site for android/eclipse I changed it back from http to https.

Previously I had errors updating the IDE and believed I had changed this to http because other postings had suggested that... and that previously fixed my update issue.

Now with the latest Android / Eclipse IDE code... it appears the https is working and needed.

Comment: wow it actually worked. I'm left wondering exactly why these strange problems occur and why this solution worked

Answer (score 15):

For me, this was solved this applying the fix that [frogman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326193/frogman) suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10103295/106342).

The answer:

> Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”

The checkbox mentioned there is in the dialog that shows up when you hit "Install new software".

Found this answer through [espinchi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106342/espinchi) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15543160/211292).

Comment: You sir, are a saint. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Agree with the above.

In fact you can get this from the official websites: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: With this it will be more understandable: `I just had this issue... and I went back into Window->Preferences->Install/Update and for the setting of the update site for android/eclipse I changed it back from http to https.`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had already been using http for a few years (after https wouldn't work) so changing back to https solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
1)changing "https:" to "http:" or vise versa 
2)Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”

If both the solutions don't work then manually update the ADT ::
1) Uninstall ADT using [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt)
2) Reinstall the ADT by Help -> Install New Software

Answer (score -1):

If you are still unable to use Eclipse to download the ADT plugin as a remote update site, you can download the ADT zip file to your local machine and manually install it:

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.0.zip 
1 .Download the ADT Plugin zip file (do not unpack it):
2. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
3. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
4. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
5. Select the downloaded ADT-22.6.0.zip file and click OK.
6. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
7. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
8. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
9. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
10. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.

When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.