# I'm trying to install ADT in Eclipse 4.3 Kepler

Tags: eclipse, adt

I keep getting the same error message, and I've tried every solution I've seen (change https to http, uncheck "Contact all update sites", I've manually downloaded the package)

The error I'm getting is:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xerces,2.9.0.v201101211617
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xml.resolver,1.2.0.v201005080400
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xml.serializer,2.7.1.v201005080400
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.core,1.2.0.v200908252030
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.environment,1.0.400.v200912181832
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks,1.2.200.v201203141800
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui,1.2.201.v201208292200
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.300.v201111030424
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.ui,1.1.500.v200911190730
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver,1.2.100.v201305141800
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.802.v201401101620
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.3.201.v201401132128
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.501.v201311151800
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui,1.2.401.v201310231535
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.801.v201308100603
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui,1.1.401.v201308132110

I really need some help. I'm happy to provide any information someone needs. Thanks!

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483815/an-error-occurred-while-collecting-items-to-be-installed